# I search, but I don't receive a Intent.ACTION_SEARCH event

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a search fonctionality in my android app. With my app :

1. I click on the standard search button.
2. I
       see the standard search dialog with
       my icon app.
3. I see my list of suggests items app
   when I type something in the search
   field.
4. When I choose a suggest, something
   call the *onNewIntent* of my standard
   activity, but the intent is
   *Intent.ACTION_VIEW*, not
   *Intent.ACTION_SEARCH*, as I hope ??

I'm losted If it's ok to receive ACTION_VIEW, how I retreive the item searched ? If it's not ok, why ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is the Intent.ACTION_VIEW, you can retrieve the data by using

```
intent.getData()
```

which will return a URI that you can parse.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That return null for me. Perhaps it's because I don't set the data with my suggest system ? How is it possible to do that ?

Comment: When you create the Intent you would use intent.setData(uri). You have to use this since the ACTION_VIEW doesn't send any EXTRAS that I am aware of.

Comment: But I don't create the intent ! I receive this intent with onNewIntent, from a search operation (I hope, I don't understand very well all that stuff).

Comment: Would you mind posting some code of where you initialize the search. And perhaps where you get the Intent.